# How to convert a time string to seconds?

Tags: python, time, python-datetime

I need to convert time value strings given in the following format to seconds, for example:

```
1.'00:00:00,000' -> 0 seconds

2.'00:00:10,000' -> 10 seconds

3.'00:01:04,000' -> 64 seconds

4.'01:01:09,000' -> 3669 seconds
```

Do I need to use regex to do this? I tried to use the time module, but

```
time.strptime('00:00:00,000','%I:%M:%S')
```

throws:

```
ValueError: time data '00:00:00,000' does not match format '%I:%M:%S'
```

---

**Edit**:

Looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
pt = datetime.strptime(timestring,'%H:%M:%S,%f')
total_seconds = pt.second + pt.minute*60 + pt.hour*3600
```

gives the correct result. I was just using the wrong module.

Comment: You don't need to use `datatime.datetime.strptime`, `time.strptime` works for that as well, it's just not in the documentation for some reason...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
import datetime
import time
x = time.strptime('00:01:00,000'.split(',')[0],'%H:%M:%S')
datetime.timedelta(hours=x.tm_hour,minutes=x.tm_min,seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()
60.0
```

Answer (score 44):

A little more pythonic way I think would be:

```
timestr = '00:04:23'

ftr = [3600,60,1]

sum([a*b for a,b in zip(ftr, map(int,timestr.split(':')))])
```

Output is 263Sec.

I would be interested to see if anyone could simplify it further.

Comment: List comprehensions are more pythonic. So `sum([a*b for a,b in zip(ftr, [int(i) for i in timestr.split(":")])])` would be more pythonic.

Comment: Thanks Le Vieux Gildas.. it should be 263.. ftr should not have been [3600,60,0].. it must be [3600,60,1]... thanks agian

Comment: you forgot to convert the string into an integer => lambda x : sum([int(x)*int(y) for x,y in zip([3600,60,1],x.split(":"))])

Answer (score 34):

without imports

```
time = "01:34:11"
sum(x * int(t) for x, t in zip([3600, 60, 1], time.split(":")))
```

Comment: Excellent answer, small adjustment to be able to handle both mm:ss and hh:mm:ss formats correctly just reverse the split.`sum(x * int(t) for x, t in zip([1, 60, 3600], reversed(time.split(":"))))`

Comment: small adjustment to also handle fractions of a second (cast to float rather than int) `sum(x * float(t) for x, t in zip([1, 60, 3600], reversed(time.split(":"))))`

Answer (score 13):

To get the `timedelta()`, you should subtract `1900-01-01`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('01:01:09,000', '%H:%M:%S,%f')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9)
>>> td = datetime.strptime('01:01:09,000', '%H:%M:%S,%f') - datetime(1900,1,1)
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(0, 3669)
>>> td.total_seconds() # 2.7+
3669.0
```

`%H` above implies the input is less than a day, to support the time difference more than a day:

```
>>> import re
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> td = timedelta(**dict(zip("hours minutes seconds milliseconds".split(),
...                           map(int, re.findall('\d+', '31:01:09,000')))))
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(1, 25269)
>>> td.total_seconds()
111669.0
```

To emulate `.total_seconds()` on Python 2.6:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> ((td.days * 86400 + td.seconds) * 10**6 + td.microseconds) / 10**6
111669.0
```

Answer (score 8):

```
def time_to_sec(t):
   h, m, s = map(int, t.split(':'))
   return h * 3600 + m * 60 + s

t = '10:40:20'
time_to_sec(t)  # 38420
```

Comment: adding an explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're willing to strip fractions of a second... the problem is you can't use '00' as the hour with `%I`

```
>>> time.strptime('00:00:00,000'.split(',')[0],'%H:%M:%S')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is always parsing by hand

```
>>> import re
>>> ts = ['00:00:00,000', '00:00:10,000', '00:01:04,000', '01:01:09,000']
>>> for t in ts:
...     times = map(int, re.split(r"[:,]", t))
...     print t, times[0]*3600+times[1]*60+times[2]+times[3]/1000.
... 
00:00:00,000 0.0
00:00:10,000 10.0
00:01:04,000 64.0
01:01:09,000 3669.0
>>>
```

Comment: I hate doing things by hand in Python :p

Answer (score 4):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

t1 = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
time.sleep(3)
now = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print((now - t1).total_seconds())
```

result:
    3.0

Answer (score 4):

`.total_seconds()` seems to be **straightforward**.

```
from datetime import datetime

FMT = '%H:%M:%S.%f'

#example
s2 = '11:01:49.897'
s1 = '10:59:26.754'

# calculate difference
pt = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)

# compute seconds number (answer)
total_seconds = pt.total_seconds()
# output: 143.143
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [sverrir-sigmundarson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779521/sverrir-sigmundarson) comment:

```
def time_to_sec(time_str):
    return sum(x * int(t) for x, t in zip([1, 60, 3600], reversed(time_str.split(":"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def time_to_sec(time):
    sep = ','
    rest = time.split(sep, 1)[0]
    splitted = rest.split(":")
    emel = len(splitted) - 1
    i = 0
    summa = 0
    for numb in splitted:
        szor = 60 ** (emel - i)
        i += 1
        summa += int(numb) * szor
    return summa
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic solution for HH:MM:SS and MM:SS. If you want to handle a command, use `split(',')` divide by 1000 or something and then add.

```py
_time = 'SS'
_time = 'MM:SS'
_time = 'HH:MM:SS'
seconds = sum(int(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(_time.split(':'))))
# multiple timestamps
_times = ['MM:SS', 'HH:MM:SS', 'SS']
_times = [sum(int(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(_time.split(':')))) for _time in times]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `functools.reduce`?

```py
from functools import reduce

def str_to_seconds(t):
    reduce(lambda prev, next: prev * 60 + next, [float(x) for x in t.replace(',', '.').split(":")], 0)
```

One function, works on either `10,40`, `09:12,40` or `02:08:14,59`. If you use `.` instead of `,` for decimal sign it's even more simpler:

```py
def str_to_seconds(t):
    reduce(lambda prev, next: prev * 60 + next, [float(x) for x in t.split(":")], 0)
```