# How to convert to Time Duration

Tags: python

The time duration is being described using four sets of double digits numbers separated with columns such as `00:02:01:16`.
I know that this represents a time interval or a time duration.
I would like to translate it to a single number that represents a time duration in a more common form such as "120 seconds" or "12 minutes". What approach should be taken here?

Comment: Have you tried the things listed in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663720/converting-a-time-string-to-seconds-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
", ".join((a+b for a,b in zip(time_s.split(":")," hour(s), min(s), second(s), ms".split(","))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

Assume your time 00:02:01:16 is stored in `a`, which comes from `end_time - start_time`

This will be automatically be a timedelta object. Then you can use `a.total_seconds()` to get the seconds information.

Check [Timedelta Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) for more usage and examples