# How can I format time columns value from mm:ss to hh:mm:ss in python? e.g., 21:34 to 00:21:34

Tags: python, time, python-3.7, timedelta

In time column, there are values like:

```
Time
========
 59:47
 59:52
 59:53
 59:55
 1:00:01
 1:00:03
 1:00:12
```

Now, I need to reshape the values like hh:mm:ss

I have tried something like this:

```
time_list = df7['Time'].tolist()

for i in time_list:
    print(datetime.strptime(i,'%H:%M:%S'))
```

ValueError: time data ' 36:21' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61995881/10197418

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a time string to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663720/how-to-convert-a-time-string-to-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

If you can normalise your values to always be of the form `mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss`, with no additional components to them, then it's as simple as doing something like this:

```py
for time_string in time_list:
    if time_string.count(':') == 1:
        time_string = '00:' + time_string
    print(datetime.strptime(time_string,'%H:%M:%S'))
```

Let's consider the sample data posted in the question:

```
time_list = ['59:47', '59:52', '59:53', '59:55', '1:00:01', '1:00:03', '1:00:12']
```

Here's what the output of this will look like:

```
1900-01-01 00:59:47
1900-01-01 00:59:52
1900-01-01 00:59:53
1900-01-01 00:59:55
1900-01-01 01:00:01
1900-01-01 01:00:03
1900-01-01 01:00:12
```

I think, though, that since this is time data (without a date component), `time.strptime()` would be a much better candidate: just use `time.strptime()` instead of `datetime.strptime()` to get something like this:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=59, tm_sec=47, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Hope that helps! :)