# How to convert objects or string to time format when the input string/object is malformed that is %H does not exist for all rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format, timedelta

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760941/how-can-i-format-time-columns-value-from-mmss-to-hhmmss-in-python-e-g-213) has been asked before but has received no responses

I have looked through a number of forums for a solution. The other questions involve a year but mine does not - it is simply H:M:S

I web scraped this [data](https://www.hubertiming.com/results/2017GPTR10K) which returned

Time - 36:42   38:34   1:38:32   1:41:18

Data samples here: [Source data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbR5c.png) and [Source data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuzqg.png)

I need this time in minutes like so
36.70  38.57 98.53 101.30

To do this I tried this:

```py
time_mins = []
for i in time_list:
    h, m, s = i.split(':')
    math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
    time_mins.append(math)
```

But that didn't work because 36:42 is not in the format H:M:S, so I tried to convert 36:42 using this

```py
df1.loc[1:,6] = df1[6]+ timedelta(hours=0)
```

and this

```py
df1['minutes'] = pd.to_datetime(df1[6], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

but have had no luck.

Can I do it at the extraction stage? I have to do it for over 500 rows

```py
row_td = soup.find_all('td')
```

If not, how can it do it after conversion into a data frame

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a time string to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663720/how-to-convert-a-time-string-to-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input (time delta string) only contains hours/minutes/seconds (no days etc.), you could use a custom function that you apply to the column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['36:42', '38:34', '1:38:32', '1:41:18']})

def to_minutes(s):
    # split string s on ':', reverse so that seconds come first
    # multiply the result as type int with elements from tuple (1/60, 1, 60) to get minutes for each value
    # return the sum of these multiplications
    return sum(int(a)*b for a, b in zip(s.split(':')[::-1], (1/60, 1, 60)))

df['Minutes'] = df['Time'].apply(to_minutes)
# df['Minutes']
# 0     36.700000
# 1     38.566667
# 2     98.533333
# 3    101.300000
# Name: Minutes, dtype: float64
```

**Edit:** it took me a while to find it but this is a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663720/how-to-convert-a-time-string-to-seconds). And my answer here is based on [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252517/10197418).

Comment: Thank you @MrFuppes. That worked beautifully. Took me some time to understand the `[::-1]` was to reverse the split. 

As is obvious I am an absolute noob and I learnt many things today from @NileshIngle,@KaustubhBadrike and you.SO thank you all

Comment: @OldRider: happy to help! your problem is not the easiest... the `[::-1]` is a convenient alternative to `reversed()` or `.reverse` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)). Make sure to accept an answer as solution if it helped you solve the problem. Not marking an answer as solution is also a valid option though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. Below has some modifications to your code and it gets the minutes.

**Create a function**

```
def get_time(i):
    ilist = i.split(':')
    if(len(ilist)==3):
        h, m, s = i.split(':')
    else:
        m, s = i.split(':')
        h = 0
math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
return np.round(math, 2)
```

**Call the function using split**

```
x = "36:42 38:34 1:38:32 1:41:18"
x = x.split(" ")
xmin = [get_time(i) for i in x]
xmin
```

***Output***

```
[36.7, 38.57, 98.53, 101.3]
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh - Unfortunately, I am getting an error message while using your code snippet  

`NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-b798ae2c1cf8> in <module>()
      6         m, s = i.split(':')
      7         h = 0
----> 8 math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
      9 return np.round(math, 2)

NameError: name 'h' is not defined`

@Kaustubh Badrike and @MrFuppes's code snippets both worked

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with pandas, but here is something you may find useful

```
...
time_mins = []
for i in time_list:
    parts = i.split(':')
    minutes_multiplier = 1/60
    math = 0
    for part in reversed(parts):
        math += (minutes_multiplier * int(part))
        minutes_multiplier *= 60
    time_mins.append(math)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had earlier commented that @NileshIngle's response above was not working as it was giving me a

```
NameError: name 'h' is not defined.
```

A simple correction was required - moving h above m,s as it is the first variable referenced

```
h = 0 # move this above
m, s = i.split(':') 


 def get_time(i):
    ilist = i.split(':')
    if(len(ilist)==3):
        h, m, s = i.split(':')
    else:
        h = 0
        m, s = i.split(':')
    math = (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))/60
    return np.round(math, 2)
```

I would like to thank @MrFuppes, @NileshIngle and @KaustubhBadrike for taking the time to respond. I have learned three different methods.