# passing arguments to key function in itertools.groupby() to count unique values for keys

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to calculate number of unique values of some parameter at certain time with two lists - one of values and one of timestamps (they contain millisecond info that is not really relevant and must be converted to seconds).
Rn i have something like this

```
timestamps = ['00:22:33:645', '00:22:33:655', '00:22:34:645','00:22:34:745']
values = [1, 1, 2, 3]

grouped = groupby(zip(values, timestamps), lambda x: timestamp_to_seconds(x[1]))
```

but it results in

`{1353:[(1, '00:22:33:645'), (1, '00:22:33:655')], 1354:[(2, '00:22:34:645'), (3, '00:22:34:745')]}`

and i would prefer to keep only
`{1353:[1, 1], 1354:[2, 3]}`
 so `len(set(group))` would give accurate count. Is there a way to pass timestamps to key function without putting them in zip? Can lambda be skipped?

e: added actual example

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Though it seems as you could simply unpack?

Comment: `groupby` always gives you tuples of `(key, group)`. Just unpack them as yatu suggests

Comment: yes, and i want to get ```(<time_in_seconds>, <group_of_parameter_values_only>)``` not ```(<time_in_seconds>, <group_of_parameter_values_and_timestamps>)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to post-process your groupby result.  You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

**Given**

```
import time
import datetime as dt
import collections as ct


timestamps = ["00:22:33:645", "00:22:33:655", "00:22:34:645","00:22:34:745"]
values = [1, 1, 2, 3]


# Helper
def timestamp_to_seconds(ts: str) -> int:
    """Return an int in total seconds from a timestamp."""
    x = time.strptime(ts.rsplit(":", maxsplit=1)[0],"%H:%M:%S")
    res = dt.timedelta(hours=x.tm_hour, minutes=x.tm_min, seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()
    return int(res)
```

**Code**

```
def regroup(tstamps: list, vals: list) -> dict:
    """Return a dict of seconds-value pairs."""
    dd = ct.defaultdict(list)

    for t, v in zip(tstamps, vals):        
        dd[timestamp_to_seconds(t)].append(v)

    return dict(dd)
```

**Demo**

```
regroup(timestamps, values)
# {1353: [1, 1], 1354: [2, 3]}

{k: len(g) for k, g in regroup(timestamps, values).items()}

# {1353: 2, 1354: 2}
```

See also a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663720/converting-a-time-string-to-seconds-in-python) on converting timestamps to seconds.