# Value error while unpacking .split() method on string of time values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the below `array Object` which is essentially time in hours, minutes and seconds. I want to convert this object into minutes but am getting an error. The error seem to be due to different string lengths while unpacking `.split` method result. Any suggestions?

```
df6['Chip Time']
0         16:42
1         17:34
2         18:13
3         18:32
4         19:12
         ...   
1453    1:35:08
1454    1:43:41
1455    1:45:36
1456    1:45:40
1457    1:48:13
Name: Chip Time, Length: 1458, dtype: object

time_list = df6['Chip Time'].tolist()
# You can use a for loop to convert 'Chip Time' to minutes
time_mins = []
for i in time_list:
    h,m,s = i.split(':')
    math = (int(h)*3600+int(m)*60+int(s))/60
    time_mins.append(math)
print(time_mins)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-ac7d4ab91169> in <module>
      3 time_mins = []
      4 for i in time_list:
----> 5     h,m,s = i.split(':')
      6     math = (int(h)*3600+int(m)*60+int(s))/60
      7     time_mins.append(math)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: Can you provide a print statement of `i` just before `h,m,s = i.split(':')`? I think the element being passed might be off.

Comment: @Treatybreaker, I did try the print. It prints the whole list. No issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the first few rows. Let's say 2nd row `17:34`. This is what happens when you split it.

```py
In [1]: "17:34".split(":")
Out[1]: ['17', '34']
```

As you can see there are only 2 values because you have only one `:` and you are trying to unpack it to 3 variables `h,m,s` what can not be done.

You have several options to overcome this problem.

1. You could format your data differently and always include hours so `17:34` -> `0:17:34`
2. You could handle 2 cases in your parser

```py
values = i.split(':')
if len(values) == 2:
    h = 0
    m,s = values
else:
   h,m,s = values
```

3. You could use regex but I would not recommend it as it is less readable then other options

Comment: Thank you. It works and it fits into my code structure easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `0:` if length of strins is `5` by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), then connvert column to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), get seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide `60`:

```
s = df6['Chip Time'].mask(df6['Chip Time'].str.len().eq(5), '0:' + df6['Chip Time'])
df6['min'] = pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds() / 60
print (df6)
     Chip Time         min
0        16:42   16.700000
1        17:34   17.566667
2        18:13   18.216667
3        18:32   18.533333
4        19:12   19.200000
1453   1:35:08   95.133333
1454   1:43:41  103.683333
1455   1:45:36  105.600000
1456   1:45:40  105.666667
1457   1:48:13  108.216667
```

**Details**:

```
print (s)
0       0:16:42
1       0:17:34
2       0:18:13
3       0:18:32
4       0:19:12
1453    1:35:08
1454    1:43:41
1455    1:45:36
1456    1:45:40
1457    1:48:13
Name: Chip Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: This works great. It actually simplifies the code a great deal.

Comment: @Srinivas - yop, btw, dont use loops, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002)

Answer (score 1):

using a little bit of input from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252517/10197418), you could also obtain the total seconds of your timestamps as

```
def timestring_to_seconds(ts, sep=':'):  
    return sum(x * int(t) for x, t in zip((1,60,3600), reversed(ts.split(sep))))

ts = '00:04:23'
print(timestring_to_seconds(ts))
# 263

ts = '04:23'
print(timestring_to_seconds(ts))
# 263

ts = '23'
print(timestring_to_seconds(ts))
# 23
```

Note that this works even if there are only seconds (no minutes or hours) provided in the timestring. Of course you can include `/ 60` if you want minutes instead. And you can map the function to a `df` column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Chip Time': ['00:04:23', '04:23', '23']})
df['s'] = df['Chip Time'].map(timestring_to_seconds)
# df
#   Chip Time    s
# 0  00:04:23  263
# 1     04:23  263
# 2        23   23
```

Comment: And for pandas is possible use `df6['min'] = df6['Chip Time'].map(timestring_to_seconds)` ;)

Comment: @jezrael: jep, very nice, added an example. although it might be more efficient to use pandas "internal" functionality as you show in your answer

Comment: Amazing. Thanks MrFuppes and jezrael