# calculate time interval in minutes between two timestamps python

Tags: python, function, timestamp

I have two timestamps:

```
time1= "2020-01-25T01:47:35.431Z"
time2="2020-01-25T02:02:57.500Z"
```

I used the following function to calculate the time interval between the two and return it in minute and round to two decimals.

```
def app_run2_min_diff(time1,time2):
    time1= str(time1)
    time1datetime.strptime(time1,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    time2= str(time2)
    time2=datetime.strptime(time2,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    sec1=time1.strftime('%S')
    sec2=time2.strftime('%S')
    min_dif=round((float(sec2)-float(sec1)/60),2)
    return min_dif
```

My logic is that to deduct the second difference first and then convert to minute.
The min_dff I got is 34.42 , but the correct answer is 15.35. What's wrong with my logic above?

Comment: `min_dif=round(((float(sec2)-float(sec1))/60) ,2)` `float(sec1)/60` performs first in your case

Comment: @RustemQarayev thanks I fixed that but it's still not getting the correct answer

Comment: Because you are just subtracting seconds, not the actual time, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663720/how-to-convert-a-time-string-to-seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to do would be to convert `datetime.strptime` object to `datetime.timedelta` by simply subtracting two dates. Then applying simple arithmetic will give you the reuslt.

```
from datetime import datetime

time1= "2020-01-25T01:47:35.431Z"
time2="2020-01-25T02:02:57.500Z"


def to_minutes(td):
    return td.days*1440 + td.seconds/60


def app_run2_min_diff(time1,time2):
    time1 = datetime.strptime(time1,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    time2 = datetime.strptime(time2,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

    time_diff = time2 - time1
    
    min_dif = round(to_minutes(time_diff), 2)
    return min_dif
```

The result of `app_run2_min_diff(time1, time2)` will be:

```
15.37
```