# Covert time mm:ss.ms to seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a time column in my dataframe that has values like 20:14.4 and I am trying to convert it to seconds.

I have tried `df['time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1]))`  but the milliseconds at the end would not let it work. The datatype is object.
Kindly help. [image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erT8l.png)

Comment: Pls post df.dtypes

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10663851/1496419
take note of the `.%f` for your milliseconds.

Comment: data type is object

Answer (score 0):

what is the datatype of the time column?

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).dt.total_seconds()
```

to get rid of the fraction part

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QfNA.png)

`df['mins'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%M:%S.%f').dt.minute`

`df['sec'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%M:%S.%f').dt.second`

`df['Time(s)'] = ((df['mins']*60) + df['sec'])`